# Inserting into a database with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm having a problem with my database being detected. I recently added a database as you can see in the image below and my query looks right (the sql below it is what the linq is going to replace) but I'm not sure why Visual Studio is not detecting my database. When I try to add

```
using System.Data.Entities
```

I can't find it and I'm not using it already.

My current usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

The following screenshot may help you understand what I'm trying to say (open the image in a new tab to view it at 100% scale):

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You must add an `ORM` layer to your application like `Entity Framework`.

Comment: Yes you have not added Entity Data Model in your project

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Can you please elaborate on what an ORM layer is? I'm a novice unfortunately. Thanks for your response

Comment: what is Bloodbank? because your query is misformed aswell. Try reading some documentation on the Entity Framework.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I'm pretty sure I did. This (http://prntscr.com/3nd5p9) is how I added it. Did I add it incorrectly?

Comment: i can't see it in your solution explorer

Comment: [Go](https://www.google.am/search?q=ORM+layer&oq=ORM+layer&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=ORM+c%23) and learn.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I don't know if you know what you said is rude but yeah, thanks for your help but a statement like that genuinely annoys me lol

Comment: Is all right with your mind? You lost your politeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You haven't added the model to your project. I don't see any ORM-related files in Solution Explorer for `SqlIntegrationWithVs`.
2. Once you add the model, given that `BloodBank` is not the property of `Register` class; thus, it still won't exist in the current context.

   In general, ORMs put table-mapped classes in a separate namespace, for example `BloodBankDatabase.BloodBanks`, and objects which let you access table data are put in a specific class, so you'll end up with something like:

   ```
   using BloodBankDatabase;

   using (var context = new DatabaseContext(connectionString))
   {
       var returnedPerson = from loginDetails in BloodBank
                            where loginDetails.Username == usersInput
                            select loginDetails.Username;
   }
   ```

Also, looking at your code, you don't seem to understand how C# work. For example:

- You shouldn't call `cmd.Dispose()` inside the `using (SqlCommand cmd = ...) { }`, because `using` already does that.
- `SqlDataReader` implements `IDisposable`, so you've forgotten the `using () { }` around it.
- You should't catch `Exception`.
- `where Username == usersInput` doesn't make sense in this context; are you sure you understand lambda expressions?
- Don't `bool usernameTaken = false;`. Instead, declare the variable as close as possible to the location where you use it first.
- Validate your inputs before using them. What happens if `userInput` is empty? Or extremely long?

How can you improve?

1. Stack Oveflow is not a code review website. Once you get your code working (and only then), you may be interested in submitting it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
2. You may also be interested in reading a book to learn C#. [C# in Depth by Jon Skeet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/161729134X) is de facto THE book any C# beginner should read.
3. If you work in a company, insist in doing code reviews for every line of committed code. Try to get more experienced developers to review your code. If not, find someone (a friend, an old colleague) who is ready to review your code.
4. [Code analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx), available in paid versions of Visual Studio, will point out the issues like the forgotten `using () { }` blocks. This is much easier than checking on MSDN every class you use to see whether it's implementing `IDisposable`.
5. [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) is another tool which may interest you: it won't find errors per se, but will force you to use an uniform style across the code base.

Comment: @mainwa I should point out after reading your post fully in depth now I have a few responses to some things you said (no need to comment on the 100% correct things as they did help me). What do you mean by "SqlDataReader implements IDisposable, so you've forgotten the using () { } around it."? I was changing my exception earlier hence the unfinished catch. I am aware, I had the sql mentality in my head and since I couldn't see it was wrong I couldn't correct it.  I declare the item I'm going to return at the start of the method for uniform-readability. usersInput is validated in the validation

Comment: @user3653380: what I mean is that when you use any object which implements `IDisposable`, you **must** (except some very rare cases) embed it in a `using (...) { ... }`. You already did it for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` (but since you also dispose them manually, it will result in [*CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) warning), but it's missing for `SqlDataReader`, which will lead to [*CA2213: Disposable fields should be disposed*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182328.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the using statements.

Comment: I'm already using that. I'll add my using statements into the OP. Thanks for your suggestion though!